# How to search in elasticsearch python using get method

Tags: python, elasticsearch, dsl

my data in index is below

```
{'took': 0,
 'timed_out': False,
 '_shards': {'total': 1, 'successful': 1, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0},
 'hits': {'total': {'value': 4, 'relation': 'eq'},
  'max_score': 1.0,
  'hits': [{'_index': 'my-index_1',
    '_type': '_doc',
    '_id': 'COdBR3MB5PHr9J6CaD9A',
    '_score': 1.0,
    '_source': {'id': '1', 'data': 'Health'}},
   {'_index': 'my-index_1',
    '_type': '_doc',
    '_id': 'CedBR3MB5PHr9J6CaD_S',
    '_score': 1.0,
    '_source': {'id': '2', 'data': 'countries'}},
   {'_index': 'my-index_1',
    '_type': '_doc',
    '_id': 'CudBR3MB5PHr9J6CaD_Z',
    '_score': 1.0,
    '_source': {'id': '3', 'data': 'countries currency'}},
   {'_index': 'my-index_1',
    '_type': '_doc',
    '_id': 'C-dBR3MB5PHr9J6CaD_g',
    '_score': 1.0,
    '_source': {'id': '4', 'data': 'countries language'}}]}}
```

Q1. * How to get the `id=4`using get method?

My code is below which is not working

```
firstdoc = es.get(index="my-index_1",  id='4')
print(firstdoc['_source'])
```

`NotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)`

Expected out

```
{'_index': 'my-index_1',
        '_type': '_doc',
        '_id': 'C-dBR3MB5PHr9J6CaD_g',
        '_score': 1.0,
        '_source': {'id': '4', 'data': 'countries language'}}
```

The code is below to push the doc to elasticsearch

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()

r = [{'id': '1', 'data': 'Health'},
 {'id': '2', 'data': 'countries'},
 {'id': '3', 'data': 'countries currency'},
 {'id': '4', 'data': 'countries language'}]

es.indices.create(index='my-index_1', ignore=400)
for e in enumerate(r):
    #es.indices.update(index="my-index_1", body=e[1])
    es.index(index="my-index_1", body=e[1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.get` method id parameter refers to the elastic meta id, or _id. To get the record with a field called id containing a value of '4' you need to search/query on that with something like `es.search(index='my-index-1', body={"query": {"match": {"id": "4"}}})`. If you would like the elastic _id to be the same as the id field in r you need to modify your indexing to `es.index(index='my-index-1', id=e[1]['id'], body=e[1])`.